# How does sizeof() work with a dereference?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

A recent code sample i saw:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x {
       int a;
       int b;
};

int main(void) {

    struct x *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

- How does `sizeof(*ptr)` even work?
- How can a undefined pointer be dereferenced and be given to `sizeof()` and yield the correct size? (surely it should result in undefined behavior since its undefined)
- Lastly does the C standard define this sort of behavior at all? (maybe showing it is legal in C, i could not find anything)

Comment: `siezof` is not a function, it's an operator that is evaluated during compile time. The compiler knows that `ptr` is a pointer to `struct x`, hence `*ptr` would be a `struct x`. The compiler knows the size of the struct from the struct definition.

Comment: Confusion is understandable here. sizeof(*ptr) looks like a function call (when the parens are used), but it's actually a compile-time operator. ptr is not dereferenced; *ptr is used to indicate the datatype at the pointer.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as “a dereference”. A _pointer_ may be _dereferenced_, which is to say, converted from a value referencing an object into the referenced object value itself.

Comment: One more thing that so far has been unsaid, the method shown in your OP is the _preferred_ method for determining a size to pass to `malloc`, the reason being less maintenance. What if the type of `ptr` changes one day from `struct x*` to `struct y*`? If you did `malloc(sizeof(struct x))`, then you would need to change that to `sizeof(struct y)` as well. However, by doing `sizeof(*ptr)`, no change is necessary, since `*ptr` is now a `struct y` type, so you get that change automatically, and the right size is always passed to `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr` is not actually dereferenced here.  The operand of the `sizeof` operator, in this case the expression `*ptr`, is looked at only for its type.

This is spelled out in section 6.5.3.4p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `sizeof` operator:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
> the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
> is evaluated; **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
> is an integer constant**

In this particular case, `*ptr` is not evaluated but it is seen to have type `struct x`, so `sizeof(*ptr)` evaluates to a constant which is the size in bytes of `struct x`.

Answer (score 2):

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is not a function call, it is an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)). It does not work on the value of `ptr`, but its type. `ptr` has been declared to be of type `struct x*` and so the compiler knows that `sizeof(*ptr)` is equivalent to `sizeof(struct x)`.

[Demonstration](https://www.online-cpp.com/I3J5pliwT7).

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator takes an expression or a parenthesized type as its argument. It does not evaluate its argument unless that argument is a variable length array. Either way, the size is determined from the type of the operand.

So, given a pointer `int *p`, `sizeof *p` yields the size of an `int` since the expression `*p` has type `int`. There is no evaluation and hence no dereference here. Alternatively, you could use `sizeof(int)` to find the size of an `int`. In the first case the operand is the expression `*p`, and in the second case the operand is the parenthesized type `(int)`.

It may be worth commenting that `struct x *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));` is a useful C idiom. The parentheses around `*ptr` are not needed since `*ptr` is an expression, not a type:

```
struct x *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

This construct is clear and easy to maintain when types change, e.g., when `struct x` is no longer desired, but now `struct y` is needed, there is only one thing to change:

```
struct y *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

After this one simple change `ptr` is a pointer to `struct y`, and the correct amount of memory has been allocated for one `struct y`.